# Finite Element Analysis formula (3D)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations

> $$\dfrac{T_{i-1, j}-2T_{i, j}+T_{i+1,j}}{\Delta x^2}+ \dfrac{T_{i, j-1}-2T_{i, j}+T_{i,j+1}}{\Delta y^2} = 0$$

Above is quoted from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cUtiasAh_Y&ab_channel=SamR). This is a finite element analysis method to solve 2D steady state heat conduction problem, may I know what is the formula for **3D steady state heat conduction problem that involves x,y and z axis**. I tried searching the internet but it seems like a lot of people only do 2D steady state analysis.

Thank you for reading and have a nice day!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're looking for is an exact analog of this formula but in 3D, use
$$\dfrac{T_{i-1, j,k}-2T_{i, j,k}+T_{i+1,j,k}}{\Delta x^2}+ \dfrac{T_{i, j-1,k}-2T_{i, j,k}+T_{i,j+1,k}}{\Delta y^2} + \dfrac{T_{i, j,k-1}-2T_{i, j,k}+T_{i,j,k+1}}{\Delta z^2} = 0.$$
Essentially you are using the finite difference approximation
$u''(x) \approx \frac{u(x-h) - 2u(x) + u(x+h)}{h^2}$ of the second derivative when $h$ is small to the Laplace equation $0 = \Delta T = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}$.